# Does using sleep in scripts consume cpu cycles?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, sh

I find a lot of sleep used in a large code base, in-order to optimize it I want to remove all the sleep used and perform those operations in an alternative way. Does using sleep command consume CPU cycle, or does in send the process to waiting state only?

Comment: Why do you think the other coders did not know klhow to code?

Comment: Which architecture? You can always read the sources and see what it does. Everything consumes CPU but usually it’s not a busy loop.

Comment: [`man sleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) and click through to [`man nanosleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html)

Comment: What is the purpose of most of the sleeps?

Comment: @PeterJ_01 If a large code base uses a lot of sleep, chances are, that indeed the previous coders or architects didn't know what they were doing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux `sleep` doesn't consume CPU cycles, at least not more than not sleeping would. If the kernel doesn't find anything better to do, it will use the time to do some useful stuff in the idle process - and if that doesn't have anything to do, the kernel would temporarily halt the CPU until an external event occurs to lower power consumption.

In any case *I'd say* that "a lot of `sleep`" usually *is* a symptom of bad coding - how did the programmer know before execution what would be the time that would be spent before the next event would occur! An IO-bound program should be ***blocked*** waiting for events most of time, not *sleeping*! If the program is CPU-bound, then it should be ***calculating*** the results most of the time, not sleeping.